# List documents in Meteor collection with duplicate first names

Tags: mongodb, meteor

My 'Programs' collection would look like this (as an array);

```
[{ FullName: "Jane Doe", CampYear: "mays15",...}, { FullName "Jane Doe", CampYear: "mays16",...},...]
```

Some people in the collection are newbies and have just one document in the collection. Others have multiple documents and are returnees. We'd like the ability to mark or flag somehow the newbies. Somehow iterate through the collection and single out those who just have one document in there. The trouble is if I have a list of, say, 150 names, for each name I'd have to have a separate find operation on the collection, which is too intensive.

I tried using aggregation via the meteorhacks:aggregate but couldn't get it to work. After loading the package, my IDE wouldn't recognize the .aggregate method at all, even on the server.

Underscore might be a worthwhile way of doing it, but I couldn't find a method that might be of assistance.

Any ideas how we could do this?

Comment: What is the complete data structure of your programs collection?

Comment: @StephenWoods The collection is imported via a csv file, so the structure is basic key:value pairs. No nested objects or arrays. There are 13 fields with either numeric or string values.

Comment: Do you have a unique identifier for each camper?

Comment: Yes, there's a recordID field that is unique for each document.

Comment: Oh, for each camper. No, other than the name being the same.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your comment, I'd probably denormalize your data.  I'd have a new collection called `CampAttendance` or something like that.  Then you'd have the structure:

```
{
  "name": "The camper's name",
  "years": ["mays2015", ...]
}
```

You can then use `upsert` to either insert a new record or `$push` another camp year onto the years array as you're importing data.

To get the camper names who are 'newbies' then, you do:

```
CampAttendance.find({ years: { $size: 1 } });
```